# How to calculate the following conditonal expectation?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I want to calculate the conditional person's correlation coefficient. But I don't know how to calculate the following expressions,especially the conditional expectation of $E[XY|X>=F^{-1}_X(p),Y>=F^{-1}_Y(q)]$. Who can help me? I want use their joint CDF to express the final result. Thanks.

[image]